# MongoSinkConnector failed to start "the configured document ID strategy all records are required to have keys which must be either maps or structs"

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ksqldb, mongodb-kafka-connector

Mongo Sink Connector failed to start with below error:

> With the configured document ID strategy, all records are required to have keys, which must be either maps or structs.

[Record Key String Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XOdz.png)

```
Configuration:
|Write Model Strategy|DefaultWriteModelStrategy|
|Max batch size|0|
|Use ordered bulk writes|true|
|Rate limiting timeout|0|
|Rate limiting batch number|0|
|Document ID strategy|FullKeyStrategy|
|Document ID strategy overwrite existing|true|
```

Actually, the table does not have a primary key, therefore I used ksql “partition by” to construct a key for the record, but it is displayed in string format rather than map or struct. How to create record key in map or struct format using ksql?

Attached error, record key format, and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

> How to create record key in map or struct format using ksql?

Use `KEY_FORMAT=JSON` (or Avro, Protobuf, etc), for example, when you create the Steam

Otherwise, add `HoistField$Key` transform to your connector definition

Comment: "HoistField$Key" worked!!